# Assigning to 'char' from incompatible type 'void'

Tags: c++

Trying to reverse a linked list with a stack but keep getting an issue trying to rewrite the data. Trying to assign a char from data type void when i pop from the stack.

```
    void CharList::reverseNodes(){

    CharNode *nodePntr;
    CharNode *pre_nodePntr;
    std::stack<char> myStack;

    pre_nodePntr = nullptr;
    nodePntr = nullptr;

    if (top){
        nodePntr = top;

        while (nodePntr != nullptr){
            myStack.push(nodePntr->data);
            nodePntr = nodePntr->pntr;
        }
        nodePntr = top;
        while (!myStack.empty()) {
            nodePntr->data = myStack.pop();
            nodePntr = nodePntr->pntr;
        }

    } else{
        std::cout << "No nodes exist to reverse." << std::endl;
    }
}
```

When trying to save data, this is the line that I'm getting the code error.

```
nodePntr->data = myStack.pop();
```

Comment: It's hard to help without seeing more code. Please create and post a [mcve].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh, this is easy! Stack::pop() method doesn't return anything (that's why void) which you are trying to assign to a char attribute. You need to use myStack.top() to get the value and then call myStack.pop() like this:

```
nodePntr->data = myStack.top();
myStack.pop();
nodePntr = nodePntr->pntr;
```